# Angular 2 - GET date

Tags: angular, angular2-template

I'm displaying date in my template:

```
<p>Datum</p>
<b>{{data.wageStatement?.date}}
```

This is how it's rendered:

```
2017-03-08T13:00:03.114Z
```

But I want to show only the date in this format:

```
2017-03-08
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `DatePipe`:

```
<p>Datum</p>
{{data.wageStatement?.date | date: 'dd-MM-yyyy' }}
```

You can find more info about `DatePipe` on [Angular's official docs page](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/index/DatePipe-pipe.html).

Answer (score 2):

i use current time and date pipe in app:

```
  birthday:any=new Date();
constructor(){
  this.birthday=Date.now();
}
```

--
and in template

```
<div>
 {{birthday | date}}
</div>
```